# Positioning networkx nodes by shared node attributes

Tags: python, layout, attributes, draw, networkx

Is it possible to position nodes in a networkx graph so that nodes sharing a certain (single) attribute are clustered near each other?

For example, if the nodes represent people and each has an attribute 'age', how can I make it so that people of the same age are near each other when I draw the graph? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the x,y coordinates of each node.  So if you have some idea on how you want it to look it can be programmed.  You could try a spring layout but this isn't going to be hit or miss, it's going to be more misses.  The way to attempt it is by connecting the nodes of the same data to each other. (people of the same age have one or more edges between them)

The only way I see this working well with large amounts of data is using a tool called [Gephi](https://gephi.org/users/download/) to manipulate by hand based on node data etc... it's like a photoshop of network graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest yet another approach. Create an extra attribute for your nodes that corresponds to a range of values of the attribute you want to use for the grouping. For example, if your attribute is age, then create ranges `18-30`, `31-40`, etc. Save the result in GraphML format and load the network with [NodeXL](https://nodexl.codeplex.com/) (*which is not free anymore but you could buy it for a small fee*)

In NodeXL you can group the nodes by some attribute and it lays out the different groups so that nodes belonging to the same group are laid out close to each other. You can also choose how nodes in a group are laid out, from a list of layout options)